# Print or export a dc.js chart

Tags: dc.js

I created different charts using dc.js but I want to add a printing option on each chart. How can I do it? Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. Could you edit it and add more information about what you're trying to do? Do you mean "print" like put a copy on physical paper? If so, I don't understand how a tooltip is related. The legend is part of the SVG, so naturally it would be printed too... but I don't think this is what you mean.

Comment: Hello @Gordon, I mean adding like a button which prints a graph either on a physical paper or exporting like a bar chart on a PDF file. And I would also like the graph to come with its legend. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about pdf (it's a complicated format), but there are a lot of tools for exporting an SVG or PNG from a chart - this isn't really specific to dc.js. You could check this recent question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281972/exporting-dc-js-chart-from-svg-to-png